# How to trigger google chrome extensions using selenium

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, google-chrome-extension, selenium-chromedriver

So am trying to trigger an audio recording extension using selenium , by Ctrl + Shift + S but nothing seems to trigger it , when i do it manually , it works perfectly fine , I tried using the send keys to body method but that didnt seem to be working at all.

Any other ways to do it?